# Unable to get data from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to hit the stored procedure from C# code but always get the result == -1. I don't know where I went wrong. I have searched a lot but didn't' find any solution. Please have a look into my code snippet and guide me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

C# code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString()))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
{
    Int32 rowsAffected;

    command.CommandText = "SP_LOGIN_GETUSERBYNAME";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", userObj.email));
    // command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userObj.email.Trim();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userObj.email.ToString());
    command.Connection = connection;

    connection.Open();
    rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();

    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Connection string:

```
return "Data Source=MUNEEB-PC;Initial Catalog=HRPayRoll;User ID=sa; Password=sa";
```

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LOGIN_GETUSERBYNAME
    @Email varchar(50)
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM [User]
    WHERE Email = @Email
GO
```

Comment: Avoid naming stored procedures with the `sp_` prefix.  That prefix is used for system stored procedures included with SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  doc;

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1**

Since your command is SELECT, it is *too* normal to get -1 as a return value.

If you wanna reach your results, you can use [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead.

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
     // This will iterate your results line by line and
     // You can get columns with zero-based values like reader[0], reader[1] or
     // can use GetXXX methods of it like GetString(0) or GetInt32(1) etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Then how can I fetch a particular row from DB? and then preform further operation on the basis of that values?

Comment: I mean to ask how can i fetch the whole object. Thanks

Comment: @Steve Ups, missed that. Fixed.

Comment: @MuneebAmjad If you know row number that you want to read _exactly_, you can set a `counter` in your `while` loop and read it when your counter to set this row number. When you reach _that_ row, you can read your column values like `reader[0]`, `reader[1]` or you can get use `GetXXX()` methods of datareader (which I almost always prefer)

Comment: @SonerGönül is there any other way to retrieve the whole row from db. and then parse it column wise  instead of the above mentioned index wise approach?